# $models value in Anguilla retrieving as undefined on Chrome console for Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1

I'm trying to retrieve the webdav url of a component using Anguilla but i see the value to be retrieved as undefined.
As suggested by Nuno i'm using

```
var x = frames[0].$models.getItem(“tcm:1-123”)
x.loadWebDavUrl()
x.getWebDavUrl()
```

Not only this function but rest all are also resulting as undefined.[image]

I'm using the below code in the js file as suggested in stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082844/getting-the-webdavurl-from-tridion-anguilla-in-the-list-view

```
    Extensions.CopyUri.prototype._execute = function CopyUri$_execute(selection) {
    selectedItem = selection.getItems()[0];
   // prompt("Copy the Item ID using Ctrl/Cmd + C:", selection.getItems()[0]);


var item = $models.getItem(selectedItem),
    webDavUrl = item.getWebDavUrl();

if (!webDavUrl) {
    // WebDavUrl for cached item hasn't been loaded yet, so lets load it.
    $evt.addEventHandler(item, "loadwebdavurl", function (event) {
        webDavUrl = item.getWebDavUrl(); // also could do event.source.getWebDavUrl()
    });
    item.loadWebDavUrl();
}
prompt("Webdav Url is ",webDavUrl);
alert(webDavUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var item = window.top.frames[0].Tridion.getApplicationWindow().$models.getItem("tcm:1-123");
item.loadWebDavUrl();
item.getWebDavUrl();
```

**upd**

1\ you should use application window context to get an access to you repository.

```
var appWindow = window.top.Tridion && window || (function (i, win) { while (!(win = window.top[i++].Tridion)) { }; return win && win.getApplicationWindow();})(0);
```

2\ shortcuts should also be used in this context

```
appWindow.$evt.addEventHandler(item, "loadwebdavurl", function (event) { console.log(item.getWebDavUrl()) });
```

3\ and then load item

```
item.loadWebDavUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks Beardcore..The above solution worked while debugging on chrome console  but still i have issues when i put the code in the js file. I'm getting undefined.

Comment: I can assume that you execute item.getWebDavUrl(); right after `load`. But load request is done asynchronously, you should track it with $evt.addEventHandler(item, "loadwebdavurl", onLoadcallback);

Comment: I updated with latest source code where i'm loading the events

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. item.getWebDavUrl() returns undefined. With item.loadWebDavUrl() and $evt.addEventHandler(item, "loadwebdavurl", function (event) {webDavUrl = item.getWebDavUrl();}); also returns undefined.
Any idea what to do?